# Get Member Name from Type class constructor

Tags: c#, oop, reflection

Is it possible to get the Name from the type member from the type's constructor?
For Example :

*Class containing member property*

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int X {get; set; }
    public GenericType<ClassA> iNeedThisName {get; set;}
}
```

*Class definition for GenericType from where I'd wish to access the value from the constructor*

```
public class GenericType<T>
{
    private _iNeedThisNameValue = null;
    public GenericType()
    {
        _iNeedThisNameValue = this.Get"IneedThisName()".ExtensionMethod();
    }
    public string idLikeToDefault { get; set;} = _iNeedThisNameValue;
}
```

Comment: Your constructor will be running well away from *any* code that deals with *storing* the resulting value. Imagine `var a = new GenericType<ClassA>(); (new ClassA()).iNeedThisName = a; (new EvilClassB()).SomeOtherName = a;`. What would you imagine your code could usefully do here? I.e. you cannot enforce that another class has exactly one property of type `GenericType<ThatClass>`.

Comment: I think you are asking if a constructor can learn the name of the variable to which the new instance is to be assigned. The answer is no, not unless you pass it in. The instance might not even be assigned to a variable at all, or be inside a list, etc.

Comment: You need to pass it in, there's no way for the constructor to learn about this.